# To add a new line before a set of characters in a line using python

Tags: python, string

I have a line of huge characters in which a set of characters keep repeating. The line is : `qwethisistheimportantpartqwethisisthesecondimportantpart`

There are no spaces in the string. I want to add a new line before the string 'qwe' so that I can distinguish every important part from the other.

Output :

```
qwethisistheimportantpart
qwethisisthesecondimportantpart
```

I tried using

```
for line in infile:
    if line.startswith("qwe"):
        line="\n" + line
```

and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work: Does it give an error, if so tell us, or does it not output what you want, if so what does it output.

Comment: that should work, but how do you process `line` further on? it's not going to write back to the input file without further coding...

Comment: What does `qwe...` have to do with `A55...`?

Comment: @Robᵩ I think that `qwe` is just an example, but the actual code uses `A55` instead of `qwe` and `A55` represents the excess stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str.replace()` can do what you want:

```
line = 'qwethisistheimportantpartqwethisisthesecondimportantpart'
line = line.replace('qwe', '\nqwe')
print(line)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re.split()` and then join with `\nqwe`:

```
import re

s = "qwethisistheimportantpartqwethisisthesecondimportantpart"

print '\nqwe'.join(re.split('qwe', s))
```

Output:

```
qwethisistheimportantpart
qwethisisthesecondimportantpart
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope this will help you

```
string = 'qwethisistheimportantpartqwethisisthesecondimportantpart'
split_factor = 'qwe'
a , b , c  = map(str,string.split(split_factor))
print split_factor + b
print split_factor + c
```

Implemented in Python 2.7 
   This yields same output as you have mentioned buddy.

**output:**

```
qwethisistheimportantpart
qwethisisthesecondimportantpart
```